# How to exclude property in EF using PCL?

Tags: entity-framework-5, portable-class-library

I've got a POCO defined, something like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMapped] // <- this is what I want to do, but can't in PCL
    public AccountCollection Accounts { get; set; }
}
```

The above has the "NotMapped" attribute, which is what I want - but it's not available in a portable class library (PCL). The thing is, the class I need is defined in an assembly that WILL be used on the portable device but it will be filled from entity framework on the web, which DOES have access to the NotMapped attribute. If I could find a way to add the property to EF's "NotMapped" list, that would be ideal.

Is there a way to get this to work? That is, a way to do what "NotMapped" does programmatically?

I've considered other workarounds, but none of them are ideal:

- Could create a DAL separate from my domain layer and translate
  between the two (but requires mapping and two models instead of one)
- Could write custom EF queries and updates to ignore the property (but means writing all the linq/SQL/procs myself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in the Context's OnModelCreating() overload. Accessing the modelBuilder parameter it's possible to find the entity and ignore specific properties. This works even when the POCO is defined in a PCL.

For example:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        // Ignore Customer.Accounts
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Ignore(c => c.Accounts); 
}
```